# Are there any disadvantages to initializing views outside of onCreateView?

Tags: android

Typically the view is an instance variable and initliazed in the `onCreateView` method as shown with the `TextView` in the example below

```
private TextView recipeTitle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_detail, container, false);
    recipeTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    return view;
}


public void setRecipeTitle(String recipeTitle) {
    this.recipeTitle.setText(recipeTitle);
}
```

Is there any disadvantage that comes with not making the `TextView` an instance variable and just accessing it from the needed method as shown below?

```
public void setRecipeTitle(String recipeTitle) {
    if (getView() != null) {        
        ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_title)).setText(recipeTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: No there is none. But then again there is no advantage either.

Comment: I always access it in second way! :)

Comment: Remember that in Java all code must be inside a class. Your code examples here would be clearer if you show the class which contains the methods shown. Most likely this is a `Fragment` subclass. You should show this explicitly so we do not have to make any assumptions.

Comment: You could use View injection libraries to get around  use of findViewById

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById` isn't the cheapest call you can make. You're encouraged to use it only when necessary.

But as long as you're not calling `setRecipeTitle` frequently, it shouldn't be too bad of a performance hit.

But it's generally safer to code defensively since users of the custom view may not know it is a more expensive to call it than they're used to.

Summary: Either code pattern will work; the former pattern (saving the `findViewById` lookup first) would be a slightly better pattern, but not by too much in this specific case.

EDIT: Another reason why it is better to do it in `onCreateView` is so that you can have simpler null checks. In the latter example, as it is written in the question, `setRecipeTitle` would throw a null reference exception if it is called before onCreateView is in the Android lifecycle. (A rare case; not sure why you would—on accident during unit testing maybe? Anyway, the Android framework lifecycle is replete with these null reference issues without any compile-time safety. ...sigh.) But if you setup the member variable in `onCreateView` (in the former example), then you can just check for that one null, instead of fixing the latter example to null check the whole chain of calls (all of which can return null in various circumstances).

Answer (score 1):

You can call `findViewById()` any time after the parent view is inflated. However, it is quite expensive. If you use your second example and call `setRecipeTitle()` frequently, you will see a significant hit to your app's performance.